# Facebook share button does not grab og tags (Response code 404)

Tags: facebook, button, share, response

When I click on the share button on [this page](http://www.mlgestion.es/es/Venta-Viviendas-Apartamento-Sur-Retamar-Almeria/59215/), Facebook doesn't recognize the parameters I'm passing through og tags.

The problem seems to be Facebook is getting a "404" Response code, according to [Open Graph Object Debuger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mlgestion.es%2Fes%2FVenta-Viviendas-Apartamento-Sur-Retamar-Almeria%2F59215%2F)

I checked the Response code from the page and get different results with different tools:

```
http://tools.seobook.com/server-header-checker/ -> 404 Not Found
http://web-sniffer.net/ -> 404 Not Found
http://httpstatus.io/ -> 200 OK
https://monitorbacklinks.com/seo-tools/http-header-status-check -> 200 OK
http://www.axandra.com/free-online-seo-tool/status-code.php -> 200 OK
```

If I telnet the server I get a "301 Moved Permanently" and the contents are returned correctly:

```
$ telnet mlgestion.es 80
Trying 46.105.153.112...
Connected to mlgestion.es.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET /es/Venta-Viviendas-Apartamento-Sur-Retamar-Almeria/59215/ HTTP/1.1
HOST: mlgestion.es

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Thu, 05 Nov 2015 13:10:50 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.23 (CentOS)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.1.6
Location: //www.mlgestion.es/es/Venta-Viviendas-Apartamento-Sur-Retamar-Almeria/59215/
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

950a
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html class="js" xml:lang="es" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="es"><head>
<title>Apartamento en venta en Sur, Retamar, Almeria [Ref.59215]. 2 dormitorios</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<meta name="description" content="¿Quieres vivir en primera linea de playa a bajo coste? te presentamos este bonito apartamento ubicado en Retamar a 70 metros de la playa, en pleno paseo marítimo, residencial...">

<meta property="og:title" content="Venta Apartamento - Sur, Retamar, Almería [59215]" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://mlgestion.es/_dat/100/44/fotos//59215/1-foto-800x535.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="450"/>
<meta property="og:image:height" content="298"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://mlgestion.es/es/Venta-Viviendas-Apartamento-Sur-Retamar-Almeria/59215/" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Oportunidad en 1ª linea de playa ¿Quieres vivir en primera linea de playa a bajo coste? te pre
...
```

Other pages of the same site are fetched correctly (without photo) by Facebook.

Comment: Check if you have any plugins/server firewall rules or something like that active, that tries to block requests by certain bots.

Comment: Thanks CBroe. No, other pages from the site are fetched without issues.

Comment: When I hit "’Fetch new scrape information" in the OG URL debugger for this URL, it tells me that your web server returns a status 404. That would explain why it cannot retrieve your OG meta data.

Comment: Yeah, that's the point. The question is WHY is it returning a 404 if the page is apparently ok.